# Change mxmlc from swf to html on ubuntu

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ubuntu-9.04

When I use mxmlc to compile my mxml file, I get swf file. Now, I want to change the config to make mxmlc compiler generate html file instead, as we can do in Eclipse or Flex Builder. Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. From [the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=compilers_123_05.html):

> The mxmlc command-line compiler does
> not generate an HTML wrapper. You must
> create your own wrapper to deploy a
> SWF file that the mxmlc compiler
> produced. The wrapper is used to embed
> the SWF object in the HTML tag. It
> includes the `<object>` and `<embed>`
> tags, as well as scripts that support
> Flash Player version detection and
> history management.

Of course, the HTML wrapper is pretty much all boilerplate, apart from the name of the .swf file it wraps. You could create one for a project at the beginning by copying an existing one and changing the .swf-file reference, and that should be good enough most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ant task to build your project. Flex Ant tasks include a html-wrapper task that generates that html. See "[Using the html-wrapper task](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html)".